# Find from every record in table one the record with most recent date in table two

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in my Ms Access 2010 project: a table Sites with site information and modality they have, and a table Visits with information about the visit.

Table Sites:
SitesID, Name, City, Modality_A (yes/no), Modality_B (yes/no), Modality_C (yes/no)

Table Visits:
VisitsID, SitesID, Startdate, VisitorID, VisitTypeID, Modality (A/B/C)

I now want to get from every record in Sites

- The number (count) of visits
- The most recent Visits.Startdate
- The corresponding VisitorID and VisitTypeID from the most recent Startdate.

When there is no Visit to a certain Site, the site still has to be on the list.

Last but not least, I want to be able to filter on Modality. So when I choose Modality A, I want only the sites with Sites.modality_A=yes and only the visits information with Modality A.

what i have so far (for Modality A):

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Sites.SitesID, Sites.Name, Sites.City, Max(IIf([Visits].[Modality]="A", [Visits].[Startdate],Null)) AS MaxOfDate, Sum(IIf(Visits.Modality="A",1,0)) AS CountOfVisits, Max(IIf([Visits].[Modality]="A",[Visits].[VisitTypeID],Null)) AS MaxOfVisitTypeID, Max(IIf([Visits].[Modality]="A",[Visits].[VisitorID],Null)) AS MaxOfVisitorID 
FROM Visits RIGHT JOIN Sites ON Visits.SitesID = Sites.SitesID 
WHERE (((Sites.SitesID) In (select Sites.SitesID from Sites where (Sites.Modality_A=Yes))) GROUP BY Sites.SitesID, Sites.Name, Sites.City ORDER BY Max(IIf([Visits].[Modality]="A",[Visits].[Startdate],Null)) DESC;"
```

This works fairly well, but has two problems:

The MAX(visitorID) does not work, it gives not the visitor which did the last visit, but the visitorID with the highest number.

The MAX VisitTypeID does not work, it gives not the VisitTypeID from the last visit, but the VisitTypeID with the highest number

I can't find how to make this work. Any ideas? A complete other SQL then what I have so far is, of course, fine too :)

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as:

- A `join` and `group by` to get the most recent date and count.
- A `join` to get the additional information about the visitor.
- A `where` clause for filtering on modality.

This looks like:

```
select sv.*, v.visitorid, v.visittypeid
from (select s.sitesId, s.name, s.modality,
             count(v.visitId) as numvisits,
             max(v.startdate) as maxdate
      from sites as s left join
           visits as v
           on s.sitesid = v.sitesId
      group by  s.sitesId, s.name, s.modality
     ) as sv left join
     visits as v
     on v.sitesId = sv.sitesId and v.startdate = sv.maxdate
where sv.modality = "A";
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for this post! The Maxdate, VisitorID and VisitTypeID are working correctly :) At this moment, the number of visits show all the visits for one site, not only the ones with visits.modality = "A".  Second point: currently only the sites are displayed that has had a visit (and modality A), but i would like to see all the sites that has modality A, also the ones without visits. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: @Lex . . . The count should only be for modality = "A".  The modality is on `sites`, which is `left join`ed throughout the query.  Sites should be appear even with  no visits.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I don't know why it is shown differently on my screen, but it doesn't matter. I have done the same thing as you proposed, only split it in two different queries. This works fine! Problem solved :)